# AWS CloudFormation conditional tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a requirement to conditionally tag resources based on user response to the downtime parameter and the value of environment defined in map. This tag is later used by the lambda function to turn off the instances at night.

I tried it like this with no luck -

Conditions -

```
    "EnvCheck": {
        "Fn::Not": [
            {"Fn::Equals": [{"Ref": "EnvironmentType"}, "prod"]}
        ]
    },
    "EnableDowntimeTag": {
        "Fn::And": [
            {"Fn::Equals": [{"Ref": "CustodianDowntime"}, "true"]},
            {"Condition": "EnvCheck"}
        ]
    }
```

Tags section

```
    "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "OwnerContact",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": "true",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "OwnerContact"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Condition" : "EnableDowntimeTag",
                    "Key": "custodian_downtime",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": "true",
                    "Value": "Offhours tz=ET"
                }
            ],
```

Any idea on how to add a conditional tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to conditionally add a tag.  The best you can do is use the condition to modify the data for the tag - either the key or value or both.  If you modify the key, then any automated searching for the expected tag key will not find resources with the modified key.  But you will get left with unnecessary tags lying around.

e.g.

```
"Tags": [
    {
        "Key": "OwnerContact",
        "PropagateAtLaunch": "true",
        "Value": {
            "Ref": "OwnerContact"
        }
    },
    {
        "Key": { 
            "Fn::If" : [
                "EnableDowntimeTag",
                "custodian_downtime",
                "no_custodian_downtime"
            ]
        },
        "PropagateAtLaunch": "true",
        "Value": { 
            "Fn::If" : [
                "EnableDowntimeTag",
                "Offhours tz=ET",
                ""
            ]
        }
    }
],
```

With this, if the condition `EnableDowntimeTag` is true, then a tag with key `custodian_downtime` is created, and a value of `Offhours tz=ET`.

If the condition is not true, a tag with key `no_custodian_downtime` is created, with an empty value.

If you are using the tags to identify resources from an automated process, this should help it to only identify the required resources - while also providing an explicit reference on those with the `no_custodian_downtime` tag that there is no downtime required - so it could be even more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Chris! I tried all the options including the one you gave. Only reason I was hesitant to use this approach is that I do not want to have unnecessary tags on my instances but looks like, at this time, this is the only solution.

Comment: Note that while it's still not possible with raw Cloudformation, the introduction of tools like AWS CDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html) make it easier to fulfil such a requirement.

Answer (score 19):

I have a similar need and don't want unused tags lying around either. I've gotten it working using the following snippet:

```
"Tags": [
  ...,
  {
    "Fn::If": [
      "MyCondition",
      {"Key": "MyKey", "Value": "MyValue"},
      {"Ref": "AWS::NoValue"}
    ]
  }
],
```

Answer (score 9):

And if you're using YAML

```
  Tags:
    - 'Fn::If':
      - MyCondition
      -
        Key: MyKey
        Value: MyValue
      - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```